# Does it matter in which order to call RegisterType in Unity injection container in C#?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Let's assume, we have several classes like this:

```
public class WorkerLevel1 : IWorkerLevel1
{
  public WorkerLevel1(IDependency1 dep1, IWorkerLevel2 workerLevel2)
  {
    ...
  }
}

public class WorkerLevel2 : IWorkerLevel2
{
    public WorkerLevel2(IDependency2 dep2)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

When we do registrations, does it matter in which order we call RegisterType method?
(lines 1-4 below)

```
container.RegisterType<IDependency1,Dependency1>();
container.RegisterType<IDependency2, Dependency2>();
container.RegisterType<IWorkerLevel2, WorkerLevel2>();
container.RegisterType<IWorkerLevel1, WorkerLevel1>();
```

Comment: Whats stopping you trying this out yourself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't matter, as long as the interfaces you're registrering are all different.

When registering the same interface multiple times however, the ordering *does* matter; in that case, each subsequent call to RegisterType will overwrite the previous registration for that interface.